# Determine correct CPU core and thread usage

Tags: cpu

I recently purchased a Xeon E3 1270 to upgrade an older LGA1155 desktop I am using as a Plex server on Ubuntu. The previous CPU was an I5-2400. I did not reinstall Ubuntu. Instead, I just ran:

```
update -initramfs -u -k all
```

as root after installing the "new" cpu.

Good news, the server boots and works! Yay! My challenge is, I'm not sure if the CPU is properly being utilized. According to https://ark.intel.com, this should be a 4 core, 8 thread CPU. However, when I run `lscpu` it only indicates 1 thread per core.

So, do I need to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch to get it to recognize the additional threads? Did I somehow get ripped off in the CPU purchase and this is not an actual E3 1270 with 8 threads?

Thanks for any help. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server.

Here is what `lscpu` displays:

```
Architecture:        x86_64 <br>
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit<br>
Byte Order:          Little Endian<br>
CPU(s):              4<br>
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3<br>
Thread(s) per core:  1<br>
Core(s) per socket:  4<br>
Socket(s):           1<br>
NUMA node(s):        1<br>
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel<br>
CPU family:          6<br>
Model:               42<br>
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz<br>
Stepping:            7<br>
CPU MHz:             1619.944<br>
CPU max MHz:         3800.0000<br>
CPU min MHz:         1600.0000<br>
BogoMIPS:            6784.83<br>
Virtualization:      VT-x<br>
L1d cache:           32K<br>
L1i cache:           32K<br>
L2 cache:            256K<br>
L3 cache:            8192K<br>
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3<br>
```

Comment: did you check your BIOS settings? Typically hyper-threading can be enabled/disabled there, although there are other places also.

Comment: *"I did not reinstall Ubuntu."* - you made a significant hardware change.  Reinstall the OS.  Maybe run a live session first to see if all the threads are being used.

Comment: I agree with the first commenter.  The linux kernel will use what it can.  No reinstall needed

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for the [reminder to check the BIOS Doug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266438/determine-correct-cpu-core-and-thread-usage#comment2143443_1266438)! I was sure I had it on there. Nope. So finding Hyper-Threading in the BIOS and enabling it did it!

I ran `update -initramfs -u -k all` again. Not sure if that was necessary. However, now `htop` shows all 8 threads working and `lscpu` reads:

```
Architecture:        x86_64 <br>
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit<br>
Byte Order:          Little Endian<br>
CPU(s):              8<br>
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7<br>
Thread(s) per core:  2<br>
Core(s) per socket:  4<br>
Socket(s):           1<br>
NUMA node(s):        1<br>
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel<br>
CPU family:          6<br>
Model:               42<br>
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz<br>
Stepping:            7<br>
CPU MHz:             2659.406<br>
CPU max MHz:         3800.0000<br>
CPU min MHz:         1600.0000<br>
BogoMIPS:            6784.79<br>
Virtualization:      VT-x<br>
L1d cache:           32K<br>
L1i cache:           32K<br>
L2 cache:            256K<br>
L3 cache:            8192K<br>
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7<br>
```

Thanks so much for the tip to go back into the BIOS. Feeling sheepish that I did not thoroughly go there first, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to know the number of cores, you can use: **nproc**